# Python Scrapy table web scraping data outside of table rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am having trouble figuring out how I can pass the date of tennis matches to my pipeline. The date of the tennis match is not part of the table. There is a weirdly formatted date on the page ('//*[@id="center"]/ul/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[1]/span/text()') that could possibly be used.

Is there a way to pass the date that is used as url parameters? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My Spider:

```
import scrapy
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

class Tennis_ExplorerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'tennis_explorer'
    allowed_domains = ['tennisexplorer.com']

    def daterange(start_date, end_date):
        for n in range(int((end_date - start_date).days)):
            yield start_date + timedelta(n)
    
    start_date = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    end_date = datetime.datetime.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)    
    start_urls = []
    start_url='https://www.tennisexplorer.com/matches/?type=all&year='
    for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
        start_urls.append(single_date.strftime(start_url+"%Y&month=%m&day=%d&timezone=-6"))


   
    def parse(self, response):
            #self.logger.debug('callback "parse": got response %r' % response)
            #Extracting the content using xpath
            time = response.xpath('//tr/td[1][@class="first time"]/text()').extract()
            match_id = response.xpath('substring-after(//tr/td[13]/a/@href, "/match-detail/?id=")').extract()
            player1 = response.xpath('//tr[not(contains(@class, "head"))]/td[2][@class="t-name"]/a[contains(@href, "/player/")]/text()').extract()
            player2 = response.xpath('//tr[not(contains(@class, "head"))]/td[1][@class="t-name"]/a[contains(@href, "/player/")]/text()').extract()
            player1_sets = response.xpath('//tr/td[3][@class="result"]/text()').extract()
            player2_sets = response.xpath('//tr/td[2][@class="result"]/text()').extract()

            
            #Give the extracted content row wise
            for item in zip(time, match_id, player1, player2, player1_sets, player2_sets):
                #create a dictionary to store the scraped info
                scraped_info = {
                    'time' : item[0],                    
                    'match_id' : item[1],
                    'player1' : item[2],
                    'player2' : item[3],                    
                    'player1_sets' : item[4],
                    'player2_sets' : item[5]
                }
    
                #yield or give the scraped info to scrapy
                yield scraped_info
```

For some reason I am getting the date fed in one character at a time.
Here is my updated code:

```
import scrapy
import datetime
import re
from datetime import timedelta



class Tennis_ExplorerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'tennis_explorer'
    allowed_domains = ['tennisexplorer.com']

#    start_urls = 'https://www.tennisexplorer.com/results/?type=atp-single&year=2020&month=07&day=27'

    def daterange(start_date, end_date):
        for n in range(int((end_date - start_date).days)):
            yield start_date + timedelta(n)
    
    start_date = datetime.datetime.today() #- datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    end_date = datetime.datetime.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)    
    start_urls = []
    start_url='https://www.tennisexplorer.com/matches/?type=all&year='
    for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
        start_urls.append(single_date.strftime(start_url+"%Y&month=%m&day=%d&timezone=-6"))

    
    def parse(self, response):  
            #Extracting the content using xpath            
            self.logger.debug('callback "parse": got response %r' % response)
            data = response.xpath('//table[@class="result"]//a[contains(@href,"match-detail")]/@href').extract()
            match_id =[re.sub('^.+=','',el) for el in data]


            data2 = response.xpath('//span[@class="tab"]/text()').get().replace(". ", "-")
            date = datetime.datetime.strptime(data2, "%d-%m-%Y").strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            
            time = response.xpath('//tr/td[1][@class="first time"]/text()').extract()
            #event_name = response.selector.xpath('//*[@id="center"]/ul/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[1]/span').extract()              
            #event_id = response.selector.xpath('//*[@id="center"]/ul/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[1]/span').extract()              
            #player1_id = response.xpath('//tr[not(contains(@class, "head"))]/td[2][@class="t-name"]/a[contains(@href, "/player/")]/text()').extract()
            player1 = response.xpath('//tr[not(contains(@class, "head"))]/td[2][@class="t-name"]/a[contains(@href, "/player/")]/text()').extract()
            #player1_odds = response.xpath('//tr[not(contains(@class, "head"))]/td[2][@class="t-name"]/a[contains(@href, "/player/")]/text()').extract()
            #player2_id = response.xpath('//tr[not(contains(@class, "head"))]/td[2][@class="t-name"]/a[contains(@href, "/player/")]/text()').extract()
            player2 = response.xpath('//tr[not(contains(@class, "head"))]/td[1][@class="t-name"]/a[contains(@href, "/player/")]/text()').extract()
            #player2_odds = response.xpath('//tr[not(contains(@class, "head"))]/td[2][@class="t-name"]/a[contains(@href, "/player/")]/text()').extract()
            player1_sets = response.xpath('//tr/td[3][@class="result"]/text()').get()
            player1_set1 = response.xpath('//tr[not(contains(@id, "b"))][contains(@id, "r")]/td[4][@class="score"]/text()').get()
            player1_set2 = response.xpath('//tr[not(contains(@id, "b"))][contains(@id, "r")]/td[5][@class="score"]/text()').get()
            player1_set3 = response.xpath('//tr[not(contains(@id, "b"))][contains(@id, "r")]/td[6][@class="score"]/text()').get()
            player1_set4 = response.xpath('//tr[not(contains(@id, "b"))][contains(@id, "r")]/td[7][@class="score"]/text()').get()
            player1_set5 = response.xpath('//tr[not(contains(@id, "b"))][contains(@id, "r")]/td[8][@class="score"]/text()').get()
            player2_sets = response.xpath('//tr/td[2][@class="result"]/text()').get()
            player2_set1 = response.xpath('//tr[contains(@id, "b")]/td[3][@class="score"]/text()').get()
            player2_set2 = response.xpath('//tr[contains(@id, "b")]/td[4][@class="score"]/text()').get()
            player2_set3 = response.xpath('//tr[contains(@id, "b")]/td[5][@class="score"]/text()').get()
            player2_set4 = response.xpath('//tr[contains(@id, "b")]/td[6][@class="score"]/text()').get()
            player2_set5 = response.xpath('//tr[contains(@id, "b")]/td[7][@class="score"]/text()').get()

            
            #Give the extracted content row wise
            for item in zip(match_id, date, time, player1, player2, player1_sets, player1_set1, player1_set2, player1_set3, player1_set4, player1_set5, player2_sets, player2_set1, player2_set2, player2_set3, player2_set4, player2_set5):
                #create a dictionary to store the scraped info
                scraped_info = {
                    'match_id' : item[0],
                    'date' : item[1],
                    'time' : item[2],                    
                    #'event_name' : item[0],                    
                    'player1' : item[3],
                    'player2' : item[4],                    
                    'player1_sets' : item[5],
                    'player1_set1' : item[6],
                    'player1_set2' : item[7],
                    'player1_set3' : item[8],
                    'player1_set4' : item[9],
                    'player1_set5' : item[10],
                    'player2_sets' : item[11],
                    'player2_set1' : item[12],
                    'player2_set2' : item[13],
                    'player2_set3' : item[14],
                    'player2_set4' : item[15],
                    'player2_set5' : item[16],
                }

    
                #yield or give the scraped info to scrapy
                yield scraped_info
```

Answer (score 0):

The data at the top of the table is in a span element with `class="tab"`. It's a unique element.

So

```
date = response.xpath('//span[@class="tab"]/text()').get()
```

Comment: When I run it through my spider, it outputs one character at a time. Do you know why this would be?

Comment: @timmyusa could you post your code ? Are you looping over the date ?

Comment: I added my updated code above. I appreciate your help and comment.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the date of the tennis matches and pass it as url parameters (it's still unclear to me why you would do that), you can go with :

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime

url='https://www.tennisexplorer.com/matches/?type=all&year='
data = response.xpath('//span[@class="tab"]/text()').extract_first()

date = datetime.strptime(data, "%d. %m. %Y")
print(date.strftime(url+"%Y&month=%m&day=%d"))
```

Output for this [page](https://www.tennisexplorer.com/matches/?type=all&year=2008&month=12&day=15) (`15. 12. 2008` as extracted input) :

```
https://www.tennisexplorer.com/matches/?type=all&year=2008&month=12&day=15
```